# Promise to Observable does not catch error correctly

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following function. I have removed unnecessary code from it to make it simpler to read.

```
add() {
    const listingId = 'xyz';

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject(Error(`error msg`));
    });

    return from(promise).pipe(
      map(() => listingId),
      catchError(error => of(error.message))
    );
  }
```

I'm subscribing to the observable like this:

```
this.service.add().subscribe(
      listingId => {
        console.log(`listingId:`, listingId);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(`Error:`, error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log(`Completed`);
      }
    );
```

The problem is that the error is catched in the next() instead of error().
The console output is:

```
listingId: error msg
Completed
```

It should be:

```
Error: error msg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've caught and handled the error and have continued with the returned observable. To re-throw the error you could use `throwError(error.message)` instead of `of(error.message)`.

Comment: @cartant That actually helped me! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in this line `catchError(error => of(error.message))` you catch error with `catchError`  and after that stream switch to `of(error.message)`, `catchError` works like `switchMap`, you processing error and switch to another observable

Comment: you can see more examples in this page https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've already read that page you mentioned and as in the example I used `catchError(error => of(`Bad Promise: ${error}`))` but @cartant already solved this for me. Should be throwError() instead of of()